# How to reload section from collectionview

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

I tried to delete a cell from `collectionview` on `didSelect` method.

Deleting the data is working well.

But I'm getting this:

> reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of
>   sections contained in the collection view after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view
>   before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted
>   or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

This is delete cell function:

```
func deleteMovie(cell: MoiveCollectionViewCell) {
var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)!
 // remove and reload data
 self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
 self.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section))
}
```

and `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` func :

```
 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //number_per_section = 3 
    if manager.movie_List.count % number_per_section  == 0
    {
        return manager.movie_List.count / number_per_section
     }
    else {  
       return manager.movie_List.count / number_per_section  + 1
         }
}
```

I just want to reload number of sections. What should I add?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to update the datasource first before you make the calls to:

```
 collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
 collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section))
```

So first delete the object in your datasource model (array, dictionary etc).

Then you can just do this:

```
 let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
 collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are just removing a `cell` from the `section` and that will definitely not work.

Once you have removed your `cell` you need to notify your `manager.movie_List` `array` too. So, remove the selectedIndex data from array and then try it out!